# how can i make a gap between a single sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

everyone, I need help

I have a sliding menu with 2 arrow button. when I hover over the button, the menu should be slide left or right.
but I need a **gap 100px** within this menu.
Example: I have infinity menu item.in my menu carousel I am showing only 8 it something like this...

[ITEM_01][ITEM_02][ITEM_03][ITEM_04]---**gap-100px**---[ITEM_05][ITEM_06][ITEM_07][ITEM_08]

when I hover right arrow, it should be started sliding like this.. please **see the position on item 4 and item 5 in both situation**...

[ITEM_02][ITEM_03][ITEM_04][ITEM_05]---**gap-100px**---[ITEM_06][ITEM_07][ITEM_08][ITEM_09]

I made sliding carousel for the menu, but I cannot make a gap between the slide.

My HTML CODE:

```
<section class="wedding-menu-left-outer">
<i class="fas fa-angle-left float-left left-arrow"></i>
    <section class="wedding-menu-left-inner">
        <ul class="main-menu-left first-menu">
            <li><a href="#">first 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
<i class="fas fa-angle-right float-right right-arrow"></i>
```

My CSS CODE:

```
ul.main-menu-left {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;}
ul.main-menu-left li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-image: 
    url(../../img/tabs/brqx_tabs_no_selected_war_0100_2017.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    padding: 0px;}
ul.main-menu-left li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    font-size: .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;}
    section.wedding-menu-left-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;}
.wedding-menu-left-outer{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;}
section.wedding-menu-left-inner {
    float: left;}
.wedding-menu-left-outer i {
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;}
```

My JQUERY CODE:

```
function makeid() {
var text = ""; var possible="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
return text;
}
let scrollSpeed = 10;
function horizontal_Menu_Width(){
$('.wedding-menu-left-outer').each(function(){
    let id = makeid();
    $(this).attr("id", id);
    //total width of horizontal menu with 2 arrow.
    let horizontalMenuWidth = $(this).width();
    // width of the arrow
    let horizontalMenuArrowWidth = $(this).children('i').outerWidth(true);
    // total-width - 2 arrow-width = menu-container width;
    let mainContainerWidth = horizontalMenuWidth - (horizontalMenuArrowWidth*2);
    $(this).children('.wedding-menu-left-inner').css('width', mainContainerWidth);  
});
}

horizontal_Menu_Width();

$('.wedding-menu-left-outer > i').on('mouseenter', function(){
// init class,ID on valiable when mouse inter
let horizontalMenuParentID = $(this).parent('.wedding-menu-left-outer')[0].id;
let leftArrow = $(this).hasClass('left-arrow');
let rightArrow = $(this).hasClass('right-arrow');
// need to find total width of "menu-inner-container" class
let horizontalMenuScrollableWidth = $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left")[0].scrollWidth;
//need to find out visible width of "menu-inner-container" class
let menuInnerContainerWidth = $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").width();
//this is the value of total scrolable area of horizontal menu
let horizontalMenuScroll = horizontalMenuScrollableWidth - menuInnerContainerWidth;
//now we need to make a scroll left of "total scrolable area"
let scrollableMenu = horizontalMenuScroll - $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").scrollLeft();

// when mouse inter in right-arrow
if(rightArrow){
    $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").animate({
        scrollLeft: horizontalMenuScroll
    },scrollSpeed*scrollableMenu);
} else if(leftArrow){
    $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
    },scrollSpeed * $("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").scrollLeft());
}
});

$('.wedding-menu-left-outer > i').on('mouseleave', function(){
let horizontalMenuParentID = $(this).parent('.wedding-menu-left-outer')[0].id;
$("#"+horizontalMenuParentID+" >.wedding-menu-left-inner>.main-menu-left").stop();
});
```

I want to make the result like this image.....

[image: two muppets]

but I already made it like this image...

[image: two muppets]

Comment: You can create 2 separated lists.

Comment: I have tried but i can't.

Comment: tried with n th child css?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css and try.

```
.wedding-menu-left-outer li:nth-child(4n){
    margin-right:40px;
 }
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/cbLreoz6/5/)

Comment: thank you.! it's almost the same idea.but when it slides then item-5 take place in item-4 and item-6 will take item-5 position...!

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: try with `nth-child(4n)`

Comment: you need to scroll 4 element at a time

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use Css nth selector, if you are sure that number li tag elements are going to be only 8 . I just added a class to you li element , example shown in codePen.

```
    .liTag:nth-child(4){ 
          margin-right:100px; 
      }

      .liTag:nth-child(5){ 
       margin-left: 100px; 
     }
```

working demo shown below https://codepen.io/sujilnt/full/QYwRNm

Comment: element will be infinity...! :)